# Event Emitter: Template not reacting to emitted event

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-event-emitter

I Have a child component that emitts an event as such

```
@Output() setAdditionalCodeValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
```

And the HTML is

```
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" class="my-mat-cell" (click)="setAdditionalCodeValue.emit(row)">
      </mat-row>
```

My parent HTML then binds to the setAdditionalCodeValue as such

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="additionalCode">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Additional Code</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="grandParent" >
    <mat-form-field class="type" let="i = index">
      <input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event, element)" (setAdditionalCodeValue)="updateAdditionalCodeHandler(element)" [(ngModel)]="countryLookupInput" autocomplete="off" (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="element.expanded" class="parent">
      <app-lookup-popup class="child" (closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)" ></app-lookup-popup>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

And the parent component looks like

```
  updateAdditionalCodeHandler(evt) {
console.log('Update Addition Code event received: ' + evt);
this.countryLookupInput = evt;
```

}

The updateAdditionalCodeHandler is not being hit as nothing is written to the console for a start.

My end goal is to update the `'countryLookupInput'`
property with a value emitted from the 'row' parameter of the child.

Strangely the `'(closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)"'` which is hooked up the same way works, go figure!

Comment: Where in your parent template is your child component? The native input element wouldn't have an event listener for ```setAdditionalCodeValue```, you defined that inside the child component, so you would need something like ```<my-child-component (setAdditionalCodeValue)="doSomething">```

Comment: `<app-lookup-popup class="child" (closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)"  (setAdditionalCodeValue)="updateAdditionalCodeHandler(element)" ></app-lookup-popup>`

Comment: In the `<app-lookup-popup>` element, You need event binding to use the `updateAdditionalCodeHandler` event

Comment: [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Comment: You should be getting an Angular compile error for using a output binding on an element that doesn't have a directive for it. The code example doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in below element :

```
 <app-lookup-popup class="child" (closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)" ></app-lookup-popup>
```

**Modified Code**

```
<app-lookup-popup class="child" (closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)" (setAdditionalCodeValue)="updateAdditionalCodeHandler(element)" ></app-lookup-popup>
```

and the other component

```
<input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event, element)"[(ngModel)]="countryLookupInput" autocomplete="off" (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">
```

If this is the component from where the event is emitted

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues in your code, first of all you handled the event on an `input` not your child component

I mean here ->

```
  <input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event, element)" (setAdditionalCodeValue)="updateAdditionalCodeHandler(element)"
```

Instead of here ->

```
  <app-lookup-popup class="child" (closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)" ></app-lookup-popup>
```

and second issue is you need to use `$event` to access value that is emitted

so the below modified code should work

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="additionalCode">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Additional Code</th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="grandParent" >
    <mat-form-field class="type" let="i = index">
      <input matInput (keyup)="toggleLookup($event, element)"  [(ngModel)]="countryLookupInput" autocomplete="off" (keydown.ArrowDown)="onDown()">
    </mat-form-field>
    <div *ngIf="element.expanded" class="parent">
      <app-lookup-popup class="child" (closeLookup)="closeLookupHandler(element)" 
 (setAdditionalCodeValue)="updateAdditionalCodeHandler($event)" ></app-lookup-popup>
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```